# c++ map class's in value

Tags: c++, class

I need to make map with value of class's. Now it's look like:

```
if (string=="Reg") {
Registration Registration(Data);
    Registration.GetResult();
}

if (string=="Auth") {
Login Login(Data);
    Login.GetResult();
}
.....
```

and I would like to do like:

```
map <std::string, class_name> ClassList;
ClassList ["Reg"] = Registration;
ClassList ["Auth"] = Login;

......

ClassList [string](Data).GetResult();
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to have a (unordered?) map of functions:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(DataCls)>> map;
map["Reg"] = [](DataCls Data) {
    Registration Registration(Data);
    Registration.GetResult();
};
map["Auth"] = [](DataCls Data) {
    Login Login(Data);
    Login.GetResult();
};
...
map[string](Data);
```

This can be simplified with this templated function:

```
template<class T>
void Handler(DataCls Data) {
    T instance(Data);
    instance.GetResult();
};

map["Reg"] = Handler<Registration>;
map["Auth"] = Handler<Login>;
...
map[string](Data);
```

Comment: thanks, and how to initialize map for map["Reg"] = Handler<Registration>?

Comment: @user1786639 I'm not sure what you mean? The code I've posted should do what you are looking for, no additional initialization is needed.

Comment: what is DataCls?

Comment: @user1786639 whatever your `Data` object is.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class IOperation
{
public:
    virtual ~IOperation(){}
    virtual int GetResult() = 0;
};

class Registration : public IOperation
{
public:
    int GetResult() override
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Login : public IOperation
{
public:
    int GetResult() override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, IOperation *> classList;

    classList["Reg"] = new Registration();
    classList["Auth"] = new Login();

    std::string cmd = "Auth";
    std::cout << classList[cmd]->GetResult();
}
```